# Function naming and launching

Tags: javascript, function

Why this is working:

JS

```
$(gallery_1 + " .gallery_comandi #next").click(function avanti_gallery() {
    contatore ++;
    if (contatore > tot_immagini) {
    contatore = 1;
    cambia_immagine ();
    }
    else {  cambia_immagine ();
    };
});
```

And this isn't? This second cose executes the function. Why? Shouldn't it be lauched by a command like avanti_gallery()?

JS

```
 function avanti_gallery() {
    contatore ++;
    if (contatore > tot_immagini) {
    contatore = 1;
    cambia_immagine ();
    }
    else {  cambia_immagine ();
    };
 };


$(gallery_1 + " .gallery_comandi #next").click(avanti_gallery());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the result, not the reference to the function.

Try this

```
$(gallery_1 + " .gallery_comandi #next").click(avanti_gallery);
```

Answer (score 1):

With

```
$(gallery_1 + " .gallery_comandi #next").click(avanti_gallery());
```

...you're **calling** the function and passing the return value into `click`, exactly the same as `foo(bar())` *calls* `bar` and passes the return value into `foo`.

Ditch the `()`:

```
$(gallery_1 + " .gallery_comandi #next").click(avanti_gallery);
// Here -----------------------------------------------------^
```

The reason your first one works is that you're only defining, not calling, the function. The `()` after the name in that expression are just part of the definition (specifically, part of the *named function expression*), whereas the `()` in the second example are actually calling the function.

It may be easier to tell the difference if we remove `click` from the picture:

Your first one:

```
var f = function avanti_gallery() {
    contatore ++;
    if (contatore > tot_immagini) {
    contatore = 1;
    cambia_immagine ();
    }
    else {  cambia_immagine ();
    };
};
```

*(I need the `var f =` at the beginning or the named function expression changes into a function declaration, which although it looks the same is quite different, and it shows visually that we're using the resulting function reference)*

Your second one:

```
var f = avanti_gallery();
```